# Column annotation with special characters

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I'm going to read a MS-ACCESS 97 Database thru a JPA compatible ORM. The point is the column name in the database has special characters:

```
@Column(name="FechPró")
Date nextDate;
```

And at execution I get this

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column not found
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.findColumn(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:1849)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getObject(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:1742)
```

Probably I have to do something like this

```
@Column(name=new String("FechPró".getBytes("ISO-8859-1")))
```

But this won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm stating the obvious but... did you try passing the compilier the encoding parameter? like in [this](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.it/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles) article?

And maybe I'm again stating the option: if you use an IDE like eclipse you can search through the preferences to set up an encoding for your project.

Comment: You were right. Changing encoding of the Netbeans project to windows-1250. Thanks !